# CSS Grid: Complex nested grid with dynamic rows

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve a layout like this using CSS Grid:

[image]

Headers and Sub 1, Sub 2, etc. are fixed, so the only growing part are the dynamic rows, a new row is added whenever the user clicks "Add item". All needs to be correctly aligned. I am trying to achieve this using CSS Grid, more or less with the following markup:

```
<div class="containter">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="subheaders"></div>
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column multicolumn">
        <input />
        <input />
        <input />
      </div>
      <div class="column multicolumn">
        <input />
        <input />
        <input />
      </div>
      <div class="column multicolumn">
        <input />
        <input />
        <input />
      </div>
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this even possible using the CSS grid? I am aware that this could maybe be achieved using a table, but since it's not exactly tabular data, we are trying to use the grid.

EDIT: Added more info to the screenshot

Comment: The image represent a table so why not use the html `<table>` for that?

Comment: You could also use a responsive grid created with ````flex-box```` or a combination of ````flex-box```` and ````grid````.

Comment: CSS-Grid would need full support of `subgrid` to do this (with your current structure) and, as has been said, this is a actually a `table` so you should use one.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added more info to the screenshot. Yes, I could use a table, but I think the markup would become a bit complex. How would you manage positioning the columns without headers, and the nested columns? Also, in the future this probably will become responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebuild your layout using a 12 column responsive grid system combined with `flex` properties.

For supporting responsive layouts you can simply add media querys for the `col` elements, e.g. `col-4-xl`, `col-6-xl`, so that it works similar the grid system of Bootstrap or Materialize.

Also you can add a parent element for the `row` class, that contains some padding to recreate the `grid-gap` property in y direction, e.g.

```
.row__parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

But this detailed changes depend on your demands.

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/KKzxmyL